# How to refresh a parent page #Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the fllowing requirement,

I have a model called Task to display user tasks

1 . Link to add a new task (in the tasks index page)

2 . when a user click the link, 'tasks/new' action will open up inside a popup

3 . when the user save the new task, I want to close 'new task' popup and refresh the 
parent page 'tasks/index' so that new task will display

I guess, i will have to execute a page reload java script at the end of 'tasks/create' action. But i'm not sure how to.

can anyone help me out to make this happen, thanks in advance

cheers,
sameera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your Task controller's `create` action redirect to the tasks index page as normal so that the newly created task shows up in the list. Then add a JavaScript `onclick` event handler to the Save button in the New Task popup. The event handler should simply perform a `window.close();` to close the popup window when the Save button is clicked. If you're using the Prototype framework, it will be something like:

```
$("save").observe("click", function() {
  window.close();
});
```

Alternatively, use JavaScript to trap the new task form submission (`onsubmit` event) and close the popup window that way.

Answer (score 0):

try window.opener.location.reload()
in your case,if you know the index page's action,you can use
redirect_to :action=>'index'

Comment: hi psjscs, thanks for the reply. Bt how can i use window.opener.location.reload()  inside the rails controller action

tasks/create,

thanks again